# How to update production database schema safely in rails 3.1.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

We need constantly update our database schema in production for rails 3.1.3 app. The first db schema was created with the following rails command:

```
$rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load
```

Question is: can we still use the command above to update db schema in production while safely retaining all current data?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I never used `rake db:schema:load` in production, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905287/rake-dbschemaload-vs-migrations) to another question here on SO, **I don't think you want to do that**.

On the other hand, I have used `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` several times on the server with data already in the database and never experienced any problems.

Comment: Tried db:migrate. It ran through each and every db migrations in the system. Current data disappeared after migrate. There seems a possibility that the current data can not be retained.