# rake db:schema:load works in development but not production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, schema, rake, production

I have searched this site and Google for hours. When I run `rake db:schema:load` everything works fine (development), but running `rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production --trace` I get the following:

```
C:\Sites\14-Meerkat>rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
Mysql2::Error: Table 'sei_mk_prod.charities' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `charities`
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Table 'sei_mk_prod.charities' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `charities`
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:286:in `query'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:286:in `block in execute'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `block in log'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:286:in `execute'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:220:in `execute'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:300:in `execute_and_free'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:461:in `columns'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:114:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `yield'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `columns'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:208:in `columns'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:247:in `column_names'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/auto_html-1.6.0/lib/auto_html/auto_html_for.rb:21:in `auto_html_for'
C:/Sites/14-Meerkat/app/models/charity.rb:9:in `<class:Charity>'
C:/Sites/14-Meerkat/app/models/charity.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
C:in `eager_load!'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
C:/Sites/14-Meerkat/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-16-2/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the charity.rb file of course. I haven't figured out the exact problem yet, but commenting out the code block starting at line 9 and a similar one in another model resolved the problem. Hope this helps some other frustrated programmer somewhere. :-)

**Update:**
One of my colleagues discovered he had initialized something in development.rb but not in production.rb. That initialization was for the code in charity.rb that was causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905287/rake-dbschemaload-vs-migrations)

Which states

> If you run rake db:schema:load on a production server, you'll end up deleting all your production data. This is a dangerous habit to get into.

Try running `rake db:migrate`. Keep running `rake db:migrate`. If you **really need** a fresh setup, did you try `rake db:reset` or `rake db:setup`?

Comment: This **is** a fresh setup. I am trying to get Windows server 2008 to serve this rails app. I have already succeeded with another rails app, so I'm not sure what the difference is. `rake db:migrate` produces the same error, as does `rake db:reset`, and `rake db:create` just tells me the database already exists. I haven't run `rake db:setup` but that's  just a shortcut for running `rake db:create`; `rake db:schema:load`, and `rake db:seed` from my understanding.