# loading new schema in database without deleting existing data rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have situation here, I have a database in production environment, and now I have to add few columns in table and drop 1 table from the database. I ran all the migrations such as `rails g migration AddDeskToHelper desk:string` and similar for dropping a table.

But now I want to upload this new generated schema into existing database without deleting any data from the database.

I'm searching about it and did not find any accurate answer.

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905287/rake-dbschemaload-vs-migrations) 
it says that rake db:schema:load deletes all the data from Database in production environment.

Kindly help me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created the migrations to add some cols in existing tables or delete some tables, the `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` command will perform an "ALTER table..." without destroying your data, except you are dropping a col or table with data content.

But it's always recommended to perform a database backup before altering your production database.